# Slow MySQL 5.7 on Windows Server 2019

Tags: mysql, performance, windows-server-2019

MySQL 5.7 standard install with standard my.cnf (server) one table 20mb size

Dell R210II Windows Server 2019 Xeon 1230 v2 16gb ram

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: CALL do_import

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 53.650 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 53.650 sec
```

Laptop i7 L620 8gb ram

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: call do_import

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 15.521 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 15.522 sec
```

Server is not loaded , it has IIS with php, Vanilla Benchmark makes :

```
Math    0.083 sec.
String  0.232 sec.
Loops   0.023 sec.
If Else 0.062 sec.
Calculation total   0.400 sec.
Total   0.400 sec.
```

Any ideas why MySQL is so slow on Xeon WS2019? I don't have any other performance issues on Dell only super slow database.

Comment: Please add details about storage, which is the most likely culprit.

Comment: What engine for the table?  Was is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size on each machine?  SSD or HDD disk?

Comment: Dell Perc H200 is a junk, write speed was about 20mb/s. The same disk in Raid1 from onboard controller: CALL do_import time drop to 10s, with H700 to 6s. Thank you for hint!